# How to set snap package to devmode?

Tags: snap, telegram

I installed telegram as a regular snap, but realised i couldn't drag-upload images this way. I don't really want to uninstall and then reinstall.

I tried:
`snap refresh --devmode telegram-desktop`

but it just replies

> 'snap "telegram-desktop" has no updates available'

The help explains the command does **"Put snap in development mode and disable security confinement"** but that's not what I see happening. What's going on?

tried switching channels but same error message.

Comment: I don't use Telegram's snap package, but according to [Telegram's snap page](https://snapcraft.io/telegram-desktop), the beta version was last updated in 2019 and is at version 1.7.12-beta which is obviously older than the current stable version 2.1.10. `devmode` doesn't update the package instead it changes the permissions. i.e. access to system resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently that does not work, although the man page of snap suggests it should. Instead remove the snap package:

`sudo snap remove telegram-desktop`

then reinstall with devmode configuration:

`sudo snap install --devmode telegram-desktop`

If already saved user configuration data is of concern for you, then you can restore the user configuration from your previous install. That is automatically saved for 31 days when you remove a snap. List the snapshots:

`snap saved`

Take note of the number of the telegram-desktop snapshot in the first column, and restore the snapshot with

`snap restore <number>`